# database in visual studio

Tags: c#, database

I'm currently developing app that requires storage of lots of information from different controls. I've never done this before, and after reading couple things on this topic got a little confused. Do I need to download SQL server 2008 and work with it in order to store data from WinForm? If yes, then what is the service-side item for? Can I use for storage?I don't need to import data from database(at least not for now), I just need stuff to save somewhere, and I would like to know where exactly. Thank you!

Comment: What sort of information are you storing and what are your requirements? A DB may be overkill. For example you may be better saving your data to a config file rather than going to the effort of setting up/managing a DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose to store your data in a serverless database (SQL CE, SQLite for example) if you don't need fancy database stuff like stored procedures, weird indexes etc. Both of the above mentioned technologies are compatible with Entity Framework, hence you can use code first approach (you can write the classes and the database would be generated on the fly).

here you can read more about it.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318010/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Let-s-Try-It

And here's SQLite assembly for .Net
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You don't **have** to store anything in a database, you could for example [serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) whatever you need to store into [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx)

Comment: The isolated storage is [constrained by a quota](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorage.quota.aspx), so may not be the best choice for storing "lots of information".

Answer (score 0):

I have read one line from your question " SQL server 2008 and work with it in order to store data from WinForm"; Mean you want to save some data and that will be coming from data entry from winform.. RIght?

If that is the case you can adopt any of the [RDBMS software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems) that suites your finance + capacity needs and other perameters.

You can surely go for SQL server 2008  or Oracle or MySql or (List will go one).

Answer (score 0):

What is the **nature** of your data?

Just because it's big does not necessarily mean a full-blown DBMS (or even an embedded database) is the best fit. Have you considered simply serializing the data to plain files?

But if your data is "relational" and you need to do the things such as querying, integrity enforcement, transactions, concurrent access by multiple clients (etc..), then you should definitely consider a database approach, including MS SQL Server, Oracle, IBM DB2, Sybase etc...

There are good open-source DBMSes as well: PostgreSQL, Firebird, MySQL...